# Spell checking beginning of phrase capital letters

Tags: spell-checking

How can I change `vim`'s spell checking, so that it does not mark words with capital letters, which were previously unknown to vim, but were added to a custom dictionary in lower case form, at the beginning of a phrase, where they suddenly have a capital letter as first letter, as wrong in general?

I know it does this for known words already, but I added a custom word:

```
lern-didaktische
```

I added it using the visual mode and selecting the whole word and then pressing `zg` to my custom file `~/.vim/spell/custom.utf-8.add`.

In the next phrase there is the same word, but at the beginning of the phrase:

```
Lern-didaktische
```

Phrases are separated by `.` and a space  in my document. Although the non-capitalized version is already known to vim and not marked as wrong anymore, this one is still marked as wrong. To be precise, the first part before the `-` is marked as wrong. However, I cannot simply add it like the other version of the word, because I don't want to allow it to have capital `L` where ever it stands. The capitalized version should *only* be correct at the beginning of phrases, because it is an adjective and we don't give adjectives a capital letter at the beginning, except at the beginning of a phrase.

Return value of `:verbose set spellcapcheck`:

```
spellcapcheck=[.?!]\_[\])'"^I ]\+
```

Comment: What does `:verbose set spellcapcheck` return?

Comment: @ryuichiro updated post